# What is the best android liberary to render vectorial tiles (geojson) from osm data?

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, geojson

I'm developing an Android application and I need to show a map from OSM data, add icons to it, and even move those icons.

I've already setup a tile server "TileStache" and it returns the geojson tiles.

Please Advice.

Comment: Please make an [edit] to include what you've tried and read [ask].

Comment: "Best" depends on many aspects. You could have a look at [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) for example, but I can't say if it matches all the requirements that you mentioned. Probably it does. And then there are services like Mapbox and Mapzen.